# Addressbook + UITableView indexing iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, addressbook

I just want to retrieve all Address book contacts and display that in UITableView.

Display that all contacts as shown in image.

I don't know how to do this.

[image]

Please suggest me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yeah, I got the solution...

Use this code

```
// creating the picker
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
// place the delegate of the picker to the controll
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

// showing the picker
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];
// releasing
[picker release];
```

and It will display all contacts from iPhone as shown in figure..but not display that type of view in simulator..you have to run it in device...

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 2):

Your frined is `ABAddressBook`: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABAddressBook_Class/Reference/Reference.html
It has `(NSArray *)people` that returns you all contacts.
You can use that as the source for your table.
I do not have complete sample code available but I think that is not the point of Stack Overflow. Search here at SO to find how to implement `UITableView`.

Comment: Actually I know how to do this but don't know how to retrieve all contacts from iPhone

Comment: As I wrote: ABAddressBook gives you the instance method "people" that returns you an array of contacts.

Answer (score 0):

[**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118772/how-to-get-contacts-detail-of-iphone-and-make-csv-file-of-that-contact/7119251#7119251) is the solution that you are looking for. In that, you will get required data from the method **-(void)collectContacts**.