# application crash on ios 11 when working with AddressBook framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, abaddressbook

I'm working on voip app. fetch contact work but when I want to make call, app crash.

> [ABSAddressBook contacts]: message sent to deallocated instance
>   0x1c1478180 warning: could not execute support code to read
>   Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of
>   type information available.

[image]

crash happen in this line.

NSArray *lContacts = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

```
    - (void) checkContactListForJogvoiceList {
//    if (![BundleLocalData isLoadingJogvoiceContactList]) {
//        [BundleLocalData setLoadingJogvoiceContactList:true];

        int maxPhoneNumberSubmit = 200;
        NSArray *lContacts = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
        NSMutableDictionary *phoneNumberContactsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *allPhoneNumberList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (id lPerson in lContacts) {
            ABRecordRef person = (ABRecordRef)lPerson;
            NSArray *phoneList = [AppUtil getContactPhoneList:person];
            for (NSString* phoneNumber in phoneList) {
                NSMutableArray* contactList = phoneNumberContactsDictionary[phoneNumber];
                if (!contactList) {
                    contactList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                }
                [contactList addObject:(__bridge ABRecordRef)person];
                phoneNumberContactsDictionary[phoneNumber] = contactList;
            }
            [allPhoneNumberList addObjectsFromArray:phoneList];

            if (allPhoneNumberList.count >= maxPhoneNumberSubmit) {
                [self checkContactList:allPhoneNumberList phoneNumberContactsDictionary:phoneNumberContactsDictionary];
            }
        }

        if (allPhoneNumberList.count > 0) {
            [self checkContactList:allPhoneNumberList phoneNumberContactsDictionary:phoneNumberContactsDictionary];
        }


        //        ABAddressBookUnregisterExternalChangeCallback(addressBook, sync_address_book, self);

//        [BundleLocalData setLoadingJogvoiceContactList:false];
//    }

}
```

probably because AddressBook framework deprecate in ios9? am I right?
I don’t want to use Contacts framework.

[image]

Comment: How you have initialised ```addressBook```?. I think it is nil due to permission issue. You should check address book permission before accessing anything.

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple doc [ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/addressbook/1621991-abaddressbookcreatewithoptions) using address book function `ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions` returns NULL if no permission granted from user.

> On iOS 6.0 and later, if the caller does not have access to the Address Book database:
>
> - For apps linked against iOS 6.0 and later, this function returns NULL.
> - For apps linked against previous version of iOS, this function returns an empty read-only database.

You should follow this article [How do I correctly use ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions method in iOS 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083643/how-do-i-correctly-use-abaddressbookcreatewithoptions-method-in-ios-6)